# Mini-Games for Artificial Intelligence Course

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence, education

I am going to have Introduction to Artificial Intelligence in this semester & I know that our main resource would be "Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach", since I want to learn deeply and Implement all the algorithms we are going to learn, I want to implement a simple intelligent mini-game for each material in the course.
so my question is that what games would be best for each topic? the only ones I could come up with were a Sudoku Solver and a simple player vs. computer Tic-Tac-Toe.

Comment: "Best" in what sense? This seems too subjective to me; what you have seems OK.

Comment: think of a game which has an agent that uses something like local search or genetic algorithm, that would be the best choice for that topic. I just want a mean to implement these algorithms.

Comment: "Hare and Hounds" comes to mind.  Search "Hare games" in Wikipedia.

Comment: Connect 4, Reversi/Othello, Mastermind...

Comment: like general question but unf agreed it is too broad for se. however two games come to mind that have a long classic history in AI: chess & go. modern algorithms are not simple but one could come up with simple algorithms. also, dynamic algorithms that play video games like pacman are very cool/ advanced, this can be done with genetic algorithms & is subj to serious scientific research. again, simple algorithms may suffice.

Comment: If you're happy with implementing just AIs instead of whole games, look at previous ICFP contests http://icfpcontest.org/ & search for older ones. They had plenty of games and other AI challenges, and you may still find submission sources by various teams and code / challenge environments to run things on. The tasks are hard, but due to the original time constraint (24h/72h) they should be small enough to tackle.